# ons-list の初期位置

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui

ons-list を使用したアプリを作成していますが，起動時に，リストを最下段までスクロールした状態で起動したいと考えています．うまい方法はないでしょうか．

Answer (score 1):

下記URLの内容のように、AngularJSの$location.hash、$anchorScrollを利用すれば、最下段までスクロールさせることができます。
問題点としては、起動時に一瞬スクロールする動きがあることと、ons-list-itemの最下段にidを設定することでしょうか。

参照URL https://teratail.com/questions/2879

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html la="ja">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
    <script>
var app = ons.bootstrap("myApp", ["onsen"]);
app.controller("page1Controller", ["$scope", "$location", "$anchorScroll", function($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {
    ons.ready(function() {
        $location.hash("scrollBottom");
        $anchorScroll();
    });
}]);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ons-navigator var="myNavigator" page="page1.html">
    </ons-navigator> 
</body>
</html>
```

page1.html

```
<ons-page ng-controller="page1Controller">
    <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="center">Navigator</div>
    </ons-toolbar>
    <ons-scroller style="width: 100%; height: 200px;">
        <ons-list>
            <ons-list-item modifier="chevron">
                1.aaa
            </ons-list-item>
            <ons-list-item modifier="chevron">
                2.bbb
            </ons-list-item>
            <ons-list-item modifier="chevron">
                3.ccc
            </ons-list-item>
            <ons-list-item modifier="chevron">
                4.ddd
            </ons-list-item>
            <ons-list-item modifier="chevron">
                5.eee
            </ons-list-item>
            <ons-list-item modifier="chevron">
                6.fff
            </ons-list-item>
            <ons-list-item modifier="chevron">
                7.ggg
            </ons-list-item>
            <ons-list-item modifier="chevron">
                8.hhh
            </ons-list-item>
            <ons-list-item modifier="chevron">
                9.iii
            </ons-list-item>
            <ons-list-item modifier="chevron" id="scrollBottom">
                10.jjj
            </ons-list-item>
        </ons-list>
    </ons-scroller>
</ons-page>
```

Comment: ng-repeat を使用した ons-list でしたが，id の設定に関しては，
id="{{$index==items.length-1 ? 'scrollBottom' : ’’}}"
のようにすればうまく行きました．