# ons-listでボタンを押したとき、先頭のlist-itemを表示させたい。

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui

ons-listと、ons-list-itemを使って、リスト表示するアプリを作りました。
listの下の方まで閲覧しているとき、メニューの「先頭を表示」ボタンを押すことで、listを巻き戻し、先頭のlist-itemから表示できるようにしたいと思っています。
どのようにすれば良いのでしょうか？

初歩的なことかもしれませんが、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

対象ノードの`scrollTop`を設定する方法もあるようなので参考程度に記載しておきます。
せっかくなので、oTakさんの記載している方法も盛り込んでみました。

```js
ons.bootstrap()
.controller('ListCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$anchorScroll', function($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {
  $scope.top = function() {
    // もっと上手い取り方があるかもしれません
    var elem = myList._element[0];
    elem.parentNode.scrollTop = 0;
  }
  $scope.top2 = function() {
    $location.hash("scrollTop");
    $anchorScroll();
  }
}]);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.6/build/css/onsenui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.6/build/css/onsen-css-components.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ons-navigator title="Navigator" var="myNavigator">
  <ons-page ng-controller="ListCtrl">
    <ons-toolbar>
      <div class="left">
        <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="top()">scrollTop</ons-toolbar-button>
        <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="top2()">anchorScroll</ons-toolbar-button>
      </div>
      <div class="center">Basic List</div>
    </ons-toolbar>
    <ons-scroller>
      <ons-list var="myList">
        <ons-list-header id="scrollTop">Numbers</ons-list-header>
        <ons-list-item>One</ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item>Two</ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item>Three</ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item>Four</ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item>Five</ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item>Six</ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item>One</ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item>Two</ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item>Three</ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item>Four</ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item>Five</ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item>Six</ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item>One</ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item>Two</ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item>Three</ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item>Four</ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item>Five</ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item>Six</ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item>One</ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item>Two</ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item>Three</ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item>Four</ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item>Five</ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item>Six</ons-list-item>

        <ons-list-header>Tappable Numbers</ons-list-header>
        <ons-list-item modifier="tappable">Tap Me</ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item modifier="tappable">Tap Me</ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item modifier="tappable">Tap Me</ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item modifier="tappable">Tap Me</ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item modifier="tappable">Tap Me</ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item modifier="tappable">Tap Me</ons-list-item>
      </ons-list>
    </ons-scroller>
  </ons-page>
</ons-navigator>

<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.6/build/js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.6/build/js/onsenui.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

[ons-list の初期位置](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/14722/ons-list-%E3%81%AE%E5%88%9D%E6%9C%9F%E4%BD%8D%E7%BD%AE)

と同様に、AngularJSを利用して、先頭のons-list-itemにidを設定し、「先頭を表示」ボタン押下時に$location.hash()、$anchorScroll()を実行すれば、先頭から表示させることができます。