# monacaのonsenUI上でのページ内遷移は可能ですか？

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui

現在monacaとonsenUIを用いてアプリを作成中なのですが、ページ内遷移のやり方がどうしても分からず困っています。
やり方を知っている方、教えてください。

Comment: `Onsen UI最小限のテンプレート`などのサンプルを開いて見てみましたか？まずはそこからやるべきでは？

Comment: 一通りの操作はできるのですが、普通なら<a href="#"></a>これで動けるはずなのですが動かないのです。

Comment: SPAの文脈ではページ内遷移という表現は誤解を生みやすいです。`pushPage()`や`popPage()`のようなページ遷移と紛らわしいため、質問文やタイトルで`<a>タグによる同一ページ内アンカリング`のように聞きたいことを強調すると良いと思います。

Answer (score 0):

このようなやり方しか思いつきませんが・・・

```
<ons-scroller style="width:100%; height: 300px;">
    <a name="top"></a>
     :
     : 省略
     :
    <a href="#top">トップへ</a>
</ons-scroller>
```

追記

AngularJSを使用してもよいのであれば、ボタン押下時に`$location.hash`、`$anchorScroll`を呼ぶやり方もあります。

参照リンク [ons-list の初期位置](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/14722/ons-list-%E3%81%AE%E5%88%9D%E6%9C%9F%E4%BD%8D%E7%BD%AE)